# How to import android support library in eclipse on mac?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos

I am trying to set up android sdk in eclipse on my mac.
I have downloaded the Android Support Library, however, there is nothing i can import to the eclipse.

I have already read through related post, and "Support Library Setup" as well.

Most people are having problems after importing the support library to eclipse and link to their own android application project, but thats not my case.

I had been stuck for days and will be really appreciated if someone can help me to solve this out.

[Screen cap of SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJUIm.png)

[Screen cap of of ../android-sdks/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAFIF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the ***.aar** file (this is archive file ).And unzip it and find **jar** files along with ressources files.after that you can add it to **libs** directory in your project.